# How to handle date format in informatica

Tags: sql, informatica

I have a scenario where I want to send the desired output to the database

The column name in database is **"DEMO_DATE" datatype TIMESTAMP**

While loading through flat file from informatica to the database 
the date value is not getting loaded.

Below is the date in value for column **DEMO_DATE**

```
2010-02-20T00:00:00.000+04:00
```

How do I need to handle this format in informatica and send the same output to the database for the *column DEMO_DATE*

Any solution will be appreciated

Thank you !!!!

Comment: What's the database? Can you show the mapping?

Comment: Have you tried converting it into a timestamp?

Comment: What's the date in your source look like?? share sample data. Then people can help on how to convert it to desired format.

Comment: The correct format in informatica is ```YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ms``` so I don't think that is your issue. However I have in the past noticed that when handling dates passed from an SQL source some problems can seemingly arise for no reason. Are all of the dates in your mapping broken or only some?

Answer (score 0):

For dates in Informatica I set the `Type` to `date/time` and then format it similar to how you did it.

date format as: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 0):

I think we are missing the point. Problem statement should be 'how to handle timestam with timezone' in informatica. Its not a straight forward process. You need to convert the TS with TZ into char to keep TZ and load as per TZ. 
Pls refer to below link -
https://network.informatica.com/thread/45996